# Error Undefined Variable en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

**El error es: Undefined Variable: prestadores**

Sucede al querer ingresar a la vista de create.blade para realizar el alta de un usuario. El codigo de aqui abajo es para que muestre en el formulario los prestadores de salud en un desplegable, los cuales estan cargados en su correspondiente tabla de la base de datos.

En el controller tengo lo siguiente:

```
public function create()
    { 
        $prestadores=DB::table('prestador/seguro')->get();
        return view('PMedicamentos.create',["prestadores"=>$prestadores]);  
    }
```

En el create.blade la parte que hace referencia a lo de arriba es lo siguiente:

```
{!!Form::open(array('url'=>'PMedicamentos','method'=>'POST','autocomplete'=>'off','files'=>'true'))!!}
            {{Form::token()}}

<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Prestador de Salud</label>
                <select name="Prestador_Seguro" class="form-control">
                    @foreach ($prestadores as $pre)
                       <option value="{{$pre->Nombre}}">{{$pre->Nombre}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Agradezco sus respuestas.

Saludos.

Comment: Es por la forma que estas trayendo tu modelo, debes hacer lo siguiente:
use App\TuModelo;

para mandarlo a traer

$tumodelo = TuModelo::all();

Comment: Tu tabla se llama prestador/seguro? O por qué la escribiste así?

Comment: si se llama asi, no le cambie el nombre

Answer (score 0):

Es por la forma que estas trayendo tu modelo, debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
use App\TuModelo;
```

para usar en tu modelo:

```
$tumodelo = TuModelo::all();

return view('PMedicamentos.create', compact('tumodelo'));
```

Compact lo que hace es retornar las variables que le envíes, puedes enviar mas separadas por comas.

Comment: ¿En donde debo ingresar esas lineas de codigo? disculpa si la pregunta es muy ignorante pero soy nuevo en todo esto jeje

Comment: Compact es igual que enviar un array asociativo.